# Off-screen navigation - right and left - css only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a right and left off-screen navigation drawer with only css and I'm having problems getting each side to work properly.

I'm using checkboxes as my buttons like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-right">
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-left">
```

If I have the toggle-right place on top then the right drawer opens, but not the left.

If I reverse the order like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-left">
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-right">
```

Toggle left will work, but not toggle right.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daugaard47/V2EWM/3/) to show you what I mean.

If someone has time to take a look and help me figure this out I would appreciate it.

While reviewing the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daugaard47/V2EWM/3/), reverse the order of the checkbox toggles to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem lies with the usage of `+` - adjacent sibling selector. As it works only for next element to your checkbox, it will only works for one of them. The solution is to use `~` - general sibling selector.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px; 
  background-color:#f1f1f1;}

.menu-toggle {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2; }

.menu-toggle:hover {
  color: #000000; }

#toggle-left {
  display: none; }
#toggle-left:checked ~ .page-wrap nav.menu {
  left: 0px; }
#toggle-left:checked ~ .page-wrap .menu-toggle {
  left: 220px; }

.profile-toggle {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
  z-index: 2; }

.profile-toggle:hover {
  color: #000000; }

#toggle-right {
  display: none; }
#toggle-right:checked + .page-wrap nav.profile {
  right: 0px; }
#toggle-right:checked + .page-wrap .profile-toggle {
  right: 220px; }

nav.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -270px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  background: #111111;
  z-index: 2000; }


nav.profile {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: -270px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  background: #990000;
  z-index: 2000; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-left">
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-right">

<div class="page-wrap">
  <header>
    <div class="top-bar">
      <label for="toggle-left" class="menu-toggle">☰</label>
      <label for="toggle-right" class="profile-toggle"><b>+</b></label>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-line"></div>
    <div class="bottom-bar"></div>
  </header>

  <nav class="menu">
  </nav>

  <nav class="profile">

  </nav>
```

Comment: I didn't realize there were other selectors. Thank you for solving this problem and teaching me something new.