# Pure CSS off-canvas left & right menu (not bootstrap) - only one of them works

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a pure CSS off-canvas left and right menu by using this source:  http://acasaprogramming.ro/pure-css-off-canvas-menu/

Their examples do contain left and right menu, but not on single page. While I try to implement them into single page, only one works (which checkbox is the first - please, see the code).

HTML:

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-left" class="toggle-left">
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-right" class="toggle-right">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-right menu-container">
            <label for="menu-right" class="close-btn">X</label>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="?date=2016-05-08" class="" data-date="2016-05-11"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i> Ням<br><span>V/08</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="?date=2016-05-09" class="" data-date="2016-05-11"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i> Дав<br><span>V/09</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="?date=2016-05-10" class="" data-date="2016-05-11"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i> Өчигдөр<br><span>V/10</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="." class="active" data-date="2016-05-11"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i> ӨНӨӨДӨР<br><span>V/11</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="?date=2016-05-12" class="" data-date="2016-05-11"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i> Маргааш<br><span>V/12</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="?date=2016-05-13" class="" data-date="2016-05-11"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i> Баа<br><span>V/13</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="?date=2016-05-14" class="" data-date="2016-05-11"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i> Бям<br><span>V/14</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="?date=2016-05-15" class="" data-date="2016-05-11"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i> Ням<br><span>V/15</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-left menu-container">
            <label for="menu-left" class="close-btn">X</label>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/" class="ui-btn-active"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw pull-right"></i><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw pull-left"></i>Нүүр</a></li>
                <li><a href="/my-bookmarks/" class=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw pull-right"></i><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw pull-left"></i>Миний Үзэх</a></li>
                <li><a href="/movies/" class=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw pull-right"></i><i class="fa fa-film fa-fw pull-left"></i>Кино</a></li>
                <li><a href="/sport/" class=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw pull-right"></i><i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-fw pull-left"></i>Спорт</a></li>
                <li><a href="/todays-top/" class=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw pull-right"></i><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc fa-fw pull-left"></i>Өнөөдрийн Шилдэг</a></li>
                <li><a href="/choose-channels/" class=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw pull-right"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw pull-left"></i>Миний Суваг</a></li>
                <li class="separator"></li>
                <li><a href="/terms-of-use/" class=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw pull-right"></i><i class="fa fa-bars fa-fw pull-left"></i>Заавар</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.localhost.local?no_redirect=1"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw pull-right"></i><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-fw pull-left"></i>Dесктоп Хувилбар</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact-us/" class=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw pull-right"></i><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw pull-left"></i>Холбоо Барих</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
            <header>
                <label for="menu-left" class="full-screen-close-left"></label>
                <label for="menu-right" class="full-screen-close-right"></label>
                <div class="menu-btn pull-right">
                    <label for="menu-right" class="toggle-btn12">
                        right menu
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-btn pull-left">
                    <label for="menu-left" class="toggle-btn">
                        left menu
                    </label>
                </div>
            </header>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.pull-left{
    float:left;
}
.pull-right{
    float:right;
}

body{
    background:#fff;
    color:#333333;
    position:relative;
}
html,
body,
.container,
.menu-container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.navbar{
    background:#232428;
    color:#ddd;
    width:280px;
}
.navbar ul{
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
}
.navbar ul li,
.navbar ul li a,
.navbar ul li span,
.navbar ul li form{
    display:block;
}
.navbar ul li form input{
    height:35px;
    padding:10px 20px;
}
.navbar ul li a,
.navbar ul li a:visited,
.navbar ul li span{
    color:#ddd;
    border-color:#3d3d3d;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border-width:1px 0 0 0;
    border-style:solid;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px 15px;
}
.navbar ul li a.active,
.navbar ul li a:hover,
.navbar ul li a:focus,
.navbar ul li a:active{
    background:#0055c5;
    border-color:#0055c5;
    color:#fff;
}
.navbar ul li a i{
    margin-left:-5px;
    margin-right:8px;
    margin-top:-1px;
}
.navbar ul li.separator{
    background:#232428;
    border:0;
    padding:10px;
}




.full-screen-close-left,
.full-screen-close-right{
    display:none;
}
.full-screen-close-left,
.full-screen-close-right{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.toggle-btn,
.close-btn{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.close-btn{
    position:absolute;
    left:280px;
    z-index:1000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
}
.navbar-right .close-btn{
    left:auto;
    right:280px;
}
.menu-container{
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
    transition:all .25s ease;
    left:-280px;
}
.menu-container.navbar-right{
    left:auto;
    right:-280px;;
}
.toggle-left:checked + .container > .menu-container.navbar-left{
    overflow:visible;
    left:0;
}
.toggle-right:checked + .container > .menu-container.navbar-right{
    overflow:visible;
    right:0;
}
.toggle-left:checked + .container > .content .full-screen-close-left,
.toggle-right:checked + .container > .content .full-screen-close-right{
    display:block;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPoqyN

Notice that if you click on "left menu", nothing happens, while if you click on the "right menu", menu shows.

How to make both menus work with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution here: [Off-screen navigation - right and left - css only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858910/off-screen-navigation-right-and-left-css-only?rq=1)

Changed from:

```
.toggle-left:checked + .container > .menu-container.navbar-left{
    overflow:visible;
    left:0;
}
.toggle-right:checked + .container > .menu-container.navbar-right{
    overflow:visible;
    right:0;
}
.toggle-left:checked + .container > .content .full-screen-close-left,
.toggle-right:checked + .container > .content .full-screen-close-right{
    display:block;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

to:

```
.toggle-left:checked ~ .container > .menu-container.navbar-left{
    overflow:visible;
    left:0;
}
.toggle-right:checked ~ .container > .menu-container.navbar-right{
    overflow:visible;
    right:0;
}
.toggle-left:checked ~ .container > .content .full-screen-close-left,
.toggle-right:checked ~ .container > .content .full-screen-close-right{
    display:block;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```